# iOS Simulator Rendering issue for PDF Reader Core for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, ios-simulator

I have searched around on here, but couldn't find anything to answer my question. I have developed a custom app for the iPad; it involves using a set of PDf documents that change pages based on a 1 second time frame. To achieve this is have used the 'PDF Reader Core for iOS' external library. Please find the link here: https://github.com/vfr/Reader

The app works perfectly fine on the actual iPad, however I also wish to run the app on Mac Mini Machines, so the obvious thought I had was to boot the project in the iOS Simulator on the machines (saves me recoding it for OSX.). Now, here is my issue. The app works pretty smoothly in the simulator, the only issue I have is that there is a slight render lag between the page change on the Simulator. It isn't at full resolution, and appears blur whilst it renders, however the time frame to change is so quick that the simulator doesn't have enough time to render to full resolution. I have also emailed the developer of the library and he provided some suggestions however, these didn't seem to fix the issue.

I am aware that this could be to do with the actual PDF Reader itself, however I wanted to ask if anyone had any suggestions if this could be fixed in regards to the iOS Simulator? Any way to speed up the simulator?

I am using OSX Yosemite, Xcode 6.4 and Objective-C.

It seems at this moment i may have to recode for OSX. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: is the simulator size scaled down in any way? that would cause it to look blurry. also a mac mini can struggle with the retina size simulators, dont think the graphics card is up to scratch in a simulated environment

Comment: can try use the iPad 2 simulator and see if the performance is any better

Comment: @Fonix thanks for your answer. The simulator was running at 100% so i don't think this was the issue, however, I did take your advice on board and rant he app in the iPad 2 Simulator and it manages to render to full resolution before changing over, so yeh that does manage to work. I then also installed the latest version of XCode (7.2) and ALL Simulators in there seem to work fine. Looks like Apple have improved the iOS Simulator for XCode 7.2.